# AWS stream and filter patterns - When value is not null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a dynamodb and when one record is deleted, a lambda is called. My question is pretty simple as I'm interested only to those records that have a parameter different from null and it's weird but I wasn't able to find it anywhere neither in the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html). It doesn't look like an edge case so I'm quite sure it's possible to do it.

Example, when a record is deleted the event is something like that:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventName": "REMOVE",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": { ... },
        "OldImage": {
          "pk": {
            "S": "mock_pk"
          },
          "address": {
            "NULL": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My filter pattern instead:

```
{
  "eventName": ["REMOVE"],
  "dynamodb": {
    "OldImage": {
      "pk": {
        "S": [{ "prefix": "REG" }]
      },
      "address": {
        "S": [{ "anything-but": [null] }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I've got this error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Invalid filter pattern definition.
```

Seems like "anything-but" is not possible to use for this case and I rather not doing it in the code if there is the possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues at play here.

1. First and foremost a String `S` cannot be null in DynamoDB, as DynamoDB maintains a separate Null bool: `"NULL": true`. So your request should not be anything-but, but instead [`exists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html#filtering-syntax), as you only want to know if the value exists as a String.
2. The exception `Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Invalid filter pattern definition` is likely caused by a syntax error and not the use of `anything-but`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that my filter was wrong but I needed to show my attempt. So that's what I needed to know actually, if I put `address: { S: [{ exists: true }] }` it filters out all the null values and works as expected. Thanks a lot!